# Why there is difference in result if I audit a website using Light house through DevTool and Web UI

Tags: performance, google-chrome, automation, lighthouse

I am trying auditing website using Google lighthouse. As given on this page https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/overview/ I tried auditing a website using Web UI and DevTools. But results are different even though hitting almost at same time
PFA screenshot[image]

[image]

Out of 4 2 parameters are matching but other 2 parameters are showing differences

Answer (score 1):

Lighthouse scores will vary within some range due to a number of factors, from the page content changing over time to testing on different machines on different networks.

Performance tools can only control for some of this; depending on your performance comparison needs, you can work to further reduce the variance through a number of steps, like

- only measuring on a single machine (vs in local DevTools vs PageSpeed Insights on one of Google's servers)
- controlling page content so you know different tests e.g. aren't falling in different branches of an A/B test, or getting different ad content in different loads
- more in-depth methods, like strictly controlling CPU throttling and using more realistic (but invasive) network throttling

Lighthouse has a few docs on these topics:

- [Score Variability](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/variability.md)
- [Network Throttling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/throttling.md)