# PageSpeed Insights / Lighthouse / Unlighthouse all gives differents results

Tags: performance, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm testing the performance of a site I just deployed, but the results are different depending on the tool I'm using. For example, while PageSpeedInsight gives me a score of 81% on mobile, Lighthouse only scores the same page 41%. And Unlighthouse on "Emulated Mobile" version scored 92%.
Each tool give consistent results over time, and I'm using Lighthouse on inconito mode.
So my questions are, why are those scores so different, and which testing tool is more trustful?

[image: Lighthouse mobile test]

[image: PageSpeed Insight mobile test]

[image: Unlighthouse test]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why there is difference in result if I audit a website using Light house through DevTool and Web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76861993/why-there-is-difference-in-result-if-i-audit-a-website-using-light-house-through)

Comment: @RickViscomi What I don't understand is that on most of the posts about this topic, people get small differences between their test results (only 2% on the post you suggest) while my results have massive differences (41% score for Lighthouse / 81% score for the same page with PageSpeed Insight). I'm not sure thoose gaps in score can be explained by, for example, the network throttling applied by Lighthouse

Comment: Are the page's contents consistent across tests, or for example does it dynamically load ads some of the time?

Comment: Yes, the content is consistent. Not sure if it makes a difference but the only "external call" my website makes is to Paypal

Comment: Different tools may use different throttling settings. That could explain why LCP and TBT values vary so widely. If you rerun the page multiple times through the same tool, are the results consistent? PSI shows the throttling settings below the "STATISTIQUES" section.